# How to shell into a locally running Python app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

new to GoogleAppEngine, this question may sound stupid... I just followed the tutorial and created a Python app, which is running locally with GoogleAppEngineLauncher. Is there any way to shell into the Python shell and play with the data structures in the running app? Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the other two answers, when you are using the dev server, you can directly invoke pdb.set_trace() which will drop you into the debugger.  Though you should run the dev server from the command line, rather than the launcher to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google App Engine Remote API for Python: Using the Remote API Shell](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_shell)

This might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

For locally running apps you can use the **Interactive Console** that is included in the **Development Console**.

> The Interactive Console allows developers to enter arbitrary Python code into a web form and execute it inside their app's environment.

Navigate to the Development Console, click the Interactive Console link on the left pane. A form with a single text area will display. Enter any arbitrary Python code you like in the text area, then submit the form to execute it.

You can find more details in App Engine Python Developement Server [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver).